# How to split a long number into pairs of digits

Tags: ruby

I have a string of a long number 12345678 and want to convert it to an array like this :

```
["12", "34", "56", "78"].
```

I have tried `array.split(//).map { |e| e.to_i  }`  but it does

```
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"]
```

Comment: Do you need to handle odd numbers of digits, and if so how? E.g. Would the input `12345` produce `["12","34"]`, `["12","34","5"]`, or `["1","23","45"]`?

Comment: Hi @JordanRunning, I want double digit numbers only.

Comment: Will your input ever have an odd number of digits? Either way, the first solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56344789/179125) solves your problem.

Comment: @JordanRunning,  I won't input any odd number, so your first solution is perfect for me. I can continue my project. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. If my answer solved your problem feel free to mark it as "Accepted." You're welcome, of course, to wait and see if any better solutions come along.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no need to use a regexp, I would do something like this:

```
12345678.to_s.chars.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
#=> ["12","34","56","78"]
```

Comment: `num.digits.reverse_each.each_slice(2).map(&:join)` would work too. Too close to your example for me to post an answer

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html) with the Regexp `/../`, which matches any pair of characters:

```
n = 12345678

arr = n.to_s.scan(/../)
# => ["12", "34", "56", "78"]
```

If you need to handle odd numbers of digits and keep the last digit, use `/..?/` instead:

```
n = 123456789

arr = n.to_s.scan(/..?/)
# => ["12", "34", "56", "78", "9"]
```

An alternative approach would be to `map` over the range `0...n.to_s.size` using the [`Range#step`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Range.html#method-i-step) method:

```
n = 123456789
str = n.to_s

arr = (0...str.size).step(2).map {|i| str[i, 2] }
# => ["12", "34", "56", "78", "9"]
```

You can see all three approaches in action on repl.it: https://repl.it/@jrunning/BlissfulAcclaimedStrategy

Comment: The best answer, imo, but I think it would be improved by removing your #1 and #3, which I consider distractions. Note you forgot to convert the elements of `arr` to integers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland #1 is the one that actually solves OP’s problem (see comments on question). I considered removing the others once that was made clear. I may yet. Also, in OP’s example output the result is an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

`p = 123456789.to_s
(0..p.length).each_cons(2).map {|i, j| "#{p[i]}#{p[j]}" if i%2 == 0}.compact`